# Overlaying a <div> with text

Tags: html, css

I need to be able to display price tags on a div.

like this

[image]

I am sure it's something to do with z index and positioning.

Comment: Stop using `<br>` to add spacing to your document. Use CSS `margin` on the elements instead.

Comment: You keep editing this question. It is now unintelligible and doesn't seem to be related to your original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you could rethink your structure and use the flex properties.

You could something of that kind see snippet below ([or breakable into 2 rows of three](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQbxqg))

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 1em 3em;
  background: tomato;
}
figure {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 2em;
}
figure img {
  position: absolute;
  transform:rotate(-10deg);
}
figcaption {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50/555/555">
    <figcaption>
      200€</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50/555/555">
    <figcaption>
      200€</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50/555/555">
    <figcaption>
      200€</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50/555/555">
    <figcaption>
      200€</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50/555/555">
    <figcaption>
      200€</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50/555/555">
    <figcaption>
      200€</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

*think: witout CSS i must be able to understand what it is about ... you did separate image and price, not a really good idea ;)*

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed the first price `span` properly. You've missed a character therefore it thinks it's not closed so you're nesting gets messed up. Close this and the width should fix.

As for the rest of it I'm not sure what you are after